# jquery plugin not applying the plugin code body to each matched element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

I am making my first file uploader jquery plugin (in coffeescript):

```
    $.fn.uploadable = (opts={}) ->
      console.log $(@).attr('type') # undefined
      event = if $(@).attr('type') is 'file' then 'change' else 'drop'
      @
      .on event, (evt) ->
        # do something
        off
      .on 'dragover', (evt) -> off


    $('#files_input, #drop_zone').uploadable
```

So you can see, in the first .on(), I am determining whether the element of the event is a browse file button or not ;if YES, then this element will be listened for "change" event when the user selects the file, if NO, then I assume it's some plain old div or something for an HTML5 drag and drop action.

So I am using the plugin on one INPUT element and one DIV element. As you can see from my console.log logged 'undefined'

So far I only know that calling method like attr(), you will only get the result from one of the listed selectors' elements. But I need to set the .on(event)'s event variable individually for each of the matched element. How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual plugin pattern looks something like this:

```
$.fn.plugin = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({ }, $.fn.plugin.defaults, options || { });
    return this.each(function() {
        // Do things to $(this) to set up your plugin.
    });
};
$.fn.plugin.defaults = { ... };
```

The CoffeeScript version would be:

```
$.fn.plugin = (options = { }) ->
    options = $.extend({ }, $.fn.plugin.defaults, options)
    @.each ->
        # Do things to $(@) to set up your plugin
$.fn.plugin.defaults = { ... }
```

The `return` part of `return this.each` is what gives you the usual chaining, the `this.each` part is what allows the plugin to bind to several things at once.

Applying this your case would give you:

```
$.fn.uploadable = (opts = { }) ->
  @.each ->
    event = if $(@).attr('type') is 'file' then 'change' else 'drop'
    $(@)
      .on event, (evt) ->
        # do something
        off
      .on 'dragover', (evt) -> off
```

Comment: I think the @.each did it! THANKS!